# Plotting DataFrame with rows containing numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a 3D-dimensional data in Pandas DataFrame:

`[sample_name] [sample_group] [wavenumber] [transmittance]`

Columns `wavenumber` and `transmittance` contains a `numpy` array of floats in each row. All these arrays are equal length.

I need to plot them on a FacetGrid with Seaborn. Different views with zoom of specific intervals of `wavenumber`.

Is it possible to make different colors for each `sample_group`?

Comment: Some sample code would help. There are examples in the [documentation](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) of plots with different colors for different groups (e.g., smoker vs. non-smoker).